# Unable to understand conditional IF statement code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following code is written for toggle-visibility of a submit button. Can you explain the conditional IF statement?

```
function ToggleVisibility(){
  var b ='btn_Submit,btn_Abort_Master';
  var temp = new Array();
      temp = b.split(',');
  var el;var i=0;
  for(i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
      try{
             el = document.getElementById(temp[i]);
      }catch(e){
          try{
             el = document.all[temp[i]];
          }catch(e){}
      }
      if (el && (el = el.style) && ('string' == typeof el.visibility){
           el.visibility = ('hidden' == el.visibility ? 'visible' :'hidden');
      }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: What conditional if?

Comment: The code is toggling the visibility of btn_Submit and btn_Abort_Master

Answer (score 1):

Its checks the following conditions :

1. that the variable el has value (meaning that the
   document.getElementById(temp[i]) or document.all[temp[i]] method call returned an element)
2. That the element el has a defined style property
3. that the style.visibility property value's type is a string

Answer (score 0):

`el` - if this variable is declared return true 
`el = el.style` - if you can to replace el with el.style return true 
`'string' == typeof el.visibility` - if el.visibility is a string return true
`if (el && (el = el.style) && ('string' == typeof el.visibility)` - if all of these statements are true do `el.visibility = ('hidden' == el.visibility ? 'visible' :'hidden');`

Answer (score 0):

```
 function ToggleVisibility(){

  var b ='btn_Submit,btn_Abort_Master';
```

> above are element on your web page taken in string (eleemnt id's)

```
 var temp = new Array();
      temp = b.split(',');
  var el;var i=0;
```

> taking an array object and splitting variable b by comma so that you
>   will get btn_Submit,btn_Abort_Master in array. So temp[0] holds first value and temp[1] second value which are element id where toggle needs to be checked and applied.

```
 for(i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
      try{
             el = document.getElementById(temp[i]);
      }catch(e){
          try{
             el = document.all[temp[i]];
          }catch(e){}
      }
      if (el && (el = el.style) && ('string' == typeof el.visibility){
           el.visibility = ('hidden' == el.visibility ? 'visible' :'hidden');
      }
  }
  return true;
}
```

> looping through the temp array length and getting the element object
>   in el. At end we are checking if element obj is present, if ele object
>   has a style and ele object type. Inside if we are toggling
>   visibility of element if hidden the visible and vice-versa.